# Camera preview failing- queueBuffer fail

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-camera

I am trying to write an app that continuously takes pictures. I have an activity and a preview class. I figured it out using an `AsyncTask` class.

```
private class CaptureTask extends AsyncTask<Boolean,Integer,Integer>
    {

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Boolean... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while(running)
            {
                if(!takingPicture&&getPreviewState()&&!p.checkCamera())
                    takePicture();
                else if(!takingPicture&&!p.getPreviewState())
                    clearPic();
            }
            return picCounter;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer pics)
        {
            t.setText("Pics taken: "+pics);
        }

    }
```

This works fine on one device, a Motorola Droid running CM7. However, when I load it on my Samsung Epic running ACS 2.3.4, I get the following error continuously until I quit the app. There is no preview shown, just black.

> 11-08 11:42:28.207: ERROR/CameraHardwareSec(76): ERR(int android::CameraHardwareSec::previewThread()):overlay queueBuffer fail
>   11-08 11:42:28.238: ERROR/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf

I've tried looking for this issue but only found a few unresolved ones.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to record video do not use

```
mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
```

to set up your media recorder even if you are working with SDK >= 8

Do the usual instead:

```
mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
```

And you will stop seeing

> android::CameraHardwareSec::previewThread()):overlay queueBuffer fail

Source of this error is mismatch between size of default camera preview and MediaRecorder video size as the error disappears when you make the sizes same with:

```
CamcorderProfile camcorderProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
parameters.setPreviewSize(camcorderProfile.videoFrameWidth, camcorderProfile.videoFrameHeight);
mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
```